# Emacs & Autocomplete: disable RET to enter?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'd like to only auto-complete when I hit the `TAB` key, and not when hitting `RET`. I've tried a number of config options, but I can't seem to disable the action. Here's my current config, which contains all the variations I've tried:

```
(define-key ac-completing-map "\t" 'ac-complete) ; use tab to complete, working
(define-key ac-completing-map "\r" nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map "\C-m" nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map "RET" nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map "<return>" nil)
```

Interestingly, `\C-m` does work as expected, but hitting `RET` doesn't.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two lines alone work for me:

```
(define-key ac-completing-map [return] nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map "\r" nil)
```

If they does not work for you, you may post the value of ac-completing-map so we can figure out what is happening.

Comment: To add to what @juanleon has said: You can find the key sequence that Emacs sees when you hit the `Return` key on your keyboard by using `C-h k` and hitting that key.  The guess here is that the answer will be `<return>` and not `RET` (aka `C-m`).

Comment: Thanks @Drew, `C-h k` shows it's `<return>` and using setting `[return]` to `nil` fixed my issue.